# What Type of Color Vision do Mantises have?

Tags: entomology, vision, senses

I am trying to figure out what type of color vision mantises have, but stuff about mantis shrimp keeps coming up instead. All I was able to find was [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2203092/) one paper from 1971. It found evidence that the ocellus have 2 photoreceptor and the compound eyes have 1 photoreceptor, but acknowledges that more could still exist:

> Although a second or third receptor type (blue or ultraviolet) was not established as present in the mantis compound eye in these studies, this lack of experimental evidence does not preclude the possibility that a second or third receptor type exists.

Have anything more definitive been done regarding mantis color vision?